# UDP Android to Win7 PC sometimes works sometimes doesn't

Tags: c#, android, windows, udp

Hi I have an Android app that sends UDP messages to an app I have running on a win7 PC.  Some days the messages go thru with no problem other days no messages show up.  I can find no reason for this.  I have days where I won't get any UDP messages on my PC and then for no reason I can ascertain the UDP messages just start showing up.  Sadly it goes the other way where they just stop coming in.  I have a second UDP server app from a co-worker that works very well on his computer but also suffers the same problem when run on my computer.  If it were a firewall issue I would think messages would never make it to me.  It seems rather random.  Rebooting devices does not fix the problem.  Any thoughts as to what is causing my inconsistent communications?  My UDP server app is written in C#.  I do not see lost UDP messages in Wire Shark traces.

Here is the code in Android that I use to send the UDP message.

```
public void SendPLMMessage(InetAddress DistIPAddress, int ServerPort, String msg) {
    int len = msg.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(msg.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(msg.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        WriteFile("exception in SendPLMMessage()\n");
    }

    try {
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, DistIPAddress, ServerPort);
        s.send(pkt);
        s.close();
        WriteFile(msg + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         WriteFile("Datagram exception\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really try supplying some source code around the UDP messaging so that this question will be a little more clear

Comment: Here is the Android code I use for sending the UDP messages: